# Работа с data/time postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Установил `dateFormat`. Подключил его себе:

```
import dateFormat from 'dateformat';
let now = new Date();
```

Далее я его использую:

```
let data = dateFormat(now, "isoDateTime");
console.log(data);
```

На сервере выводит `2019-02-05T17:31:31+0600`, а в базу данных пишется `2019-02-05` и причем в `postgre` нет ничего кроме `data` и `data[]`. Как в `postgre` записать `2019-02-05T17:31:31+0600`?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html в postgresql конечно есть timestamp. Так что смотрите схему таблицы и как вы в неё пишете

Comment: Это то что мне нужно, спасибо